# How would a register + stack based virtual machine work?

Tags: cpu-registers, register-allocation, vm-implementation, ssa, stack-based

I know how register based and how stack based virtual machines work independently. I know the advantages and disadvantages of both. What I want to know is that has anyone ever tried to merge the two?

I tried to search the net for the existence of such a virtual machine, but to no avail. The best result I got was an article on a hybrid virtual machine ([HyVM](http://www.cercs.gatech.edu/projects/HyVM/)). If such a virtual machine was indeed created for a programming language, I would be interested in having a look at its source code to understand how it works.

Perhaps someone could point me in the right direction to find such a virtual machine, or link me to an article or blog post that elaborates in this topic.

Comment: Very interesting. What specifically are you looking for? Are you looking to see what advantage the hybrid approach would have over a strictly register based VM, or stack-based VM? Your question is unclear to me.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how a hybrid virtual machine would be implemented. The advantages are pretty clear - you can evaluate expressions like `5 2 3 - +` using stack operations: `push 5`, `push 2`, `push 3`, `sub`, `add`; and then you may store the result in a register using an instruction like `store eax`. This gives you the advantages of both types of virtual machines. The entire program would be written like `x = 5 2 3 - +` where `x` is an SSA variable. What's unclear to me are the internals of the VM - is the stack in memory or on the processor, stack evaluation cost, and much more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29). It uses a VM, is mainly stack oriented but allows to store values almost in the way you suggest.

In addition, the VM is quite small, so it is easy to explore and to port it.